# unexpected field error while making post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, multer

I am getting unexpected field error while making post request ? here is my node js code

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })


// use of body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());




app.post('/upload',upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res,next) {
console.log(req.file);
console.log('hello');
res.send({data:'sss'})
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening to ${PORT}`);
})
```

I am using this plugin to upload file https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer
when I hit my service through `postman` I am getting below error

```
**App is listening to 3000
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at emitMany (events.js:147:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:224:7)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)**
```

postman Image

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the PostMan, rename the key to `avatar`

**EDIT**:
The `multer` expects the `name` of the uploaded file to be `avatar`, not `file_test`

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained why this is necessary.

Comment: [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) because the doc  also do that

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a mistake in the `roter` file.

I had:

```
router.post(
   "/addArticle",
   upload.single("image"),
   upload.array("rowPics"),
   (req, res, next)=>{...some code}
)
```

I was aiming to upload one file with the name of `image` and multiple files as an array with the name of `rowPics`. But both `upload.single` and `upload.array` cannot be used at the same time. for uploading multiple files with different names I had to change my code like below:

```
router.post(
   "/addArticle", 
   upload.fields([
      {name: "image", maxCount: 1},
      {name: "rowPics"}
   ]),
   (req, res, next)=>{...some code}
)
```

and in `...some code` section, I parsed my inputs like below:

```
let image = req.files.image[0].path
let rowPics = req.files.rowPics.map(el=>el.path)
```

and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**In Postman you enter key name wrong, you enter the FileInterceptor name in your code same name use in your Postman Key name. I hope this is helpfull** For more guide Screen shot is below!

[image]

[image]